# Quick logic deduction question

Tags: logic, proof, deduction

I have to provide a natural deduction derivation for:

> ¬∀xFx ⊢ ∃x¬Fx

That´s what I got so far:

1.¬∀xFx

2.‖ ¬∃x¬Fx (Indirect proof hypothesis)

3.‖‖ ¬¬Fy (Indirect proof hypothesis 2)

4.‖‖ Fy (from 3)

5.‖‖ ∀xFx (from 4)

Am I correct in assuming that I cannot derive ∀xFx (line 5) from Fy (line 4) because the indirect proof in line 3 is not finished (and y is not bound in line 3)?

Comment: Correct; you cannot "generalize" in 5 because y is free in the assumption 3. (still open at step 5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) **¬∀xFx** --- premise

2) **¬∃x¬Fx** --- assumed [a]

3) **¬Fy** --- assumed [b]

4) **∃x¬Fx** --- from 3)

5) **⊥** --- contradiction: from 2) and 3)

6) **Fy** --- from 3) and 5) by *Double Negation*, discharging [b]

7) **∀xFx** --- from 7): no **y** free in "open" assumptions (i.e. [a])

8) **⊥** --- contradiction: from 1) and 7)

> 9) **∃x¬Fx** --- from 2) and 8) by *Double Negation*, discharging [a]

Comment: Thank you very much! After I had realised that my original idea didn´t work, I couldn´t see that the solution is so simple! Last question: Is it necessary to end the assumptions with a double negation (make an seperate line with double negation and then eliminate it)? Or can I simply write Fy in line 6 like you did?

Comment: @LittleD - it depends on the way the [rules](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) are written.

Comment: Ok, that´s what I suspected, just wanted to ask to be sure.